# Kafka JDBC sink connector - USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka JDBC sink connector to sink data to Azure SQL server. I have tested the connector with one database and it worked fine but when I added more databases, I started seeing the following error:

**USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.**

Config:

```
    tasks.max: 1
    topics: topic_name
    connection.url: jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=dbname;user=dbuser
    connection.user: dbuser
    connection.password: dbpass
    transforms: unwrap
    transforms.unwrap.type: io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
    transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: false
    auto.create: true
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
    insert.mode: upsert
    delete.enabled: true
    pk.mode: record_key
```

Stack:

```
2020-12-10 11:56:36,990 ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=NAME-sqlserver-jdbc-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask) [task-thread-NAME-sqlserver-jdbc-sink-0]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.

        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "added more databases". You did this in the connector config?

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer  I thought in the beginning that the issue is due to having multiple databases inside the db server but turned out that the topic name has prefix.dbo.table_name in it. instead of just table_name. I have posted the details in my answer.

Comment: I was going to say - it's a standard use case to have multiple schemas in the DB server, so that wouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

I have identified the issue, I thought in the beginning that the issue is due to having multiple databases inside the db server but turned out that the topic name has `prefix.dbo.table_name` in it. instead of just `table_name`.
Hence, the connector is detecting `prefix.dbo` as another database.

The solution is to use transform dropPrefix.

Example, to save data from topic `hello.dbo.table1`,`hello.dbo.table2`  to `table1` and `table2` in the database, use the following config:

```
    tasks.max: 1
    topics: hello.dbo.table1, hello.dbo.table2
    connection.url: jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=dbname;user=dbuser
    connection.user: dbuser
    connection.password: dbpass
    transforms: dropPrefix,unwrap
    transforms.dropPrefix.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
    transforms.dropPrefix.regex: hello\.dbo\.(.*)
    transforms.dropPrefix.replacement: $1
    transforms.unwrap.type: io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
    transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: false
    auto.create: true
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter.schemas.enable: true
    insert.mode: upsert
    delete.enabled: true
    pk.mode: record_key
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work as a single connector then you'll need to create one connector per database.

Comment: It is one connector per database. The example is just to sink data from a topic to a single database.

Comment: that contradicts what you said in your question: " when I added more databases". Please clarify, and perhaps include in your question the *actual* Sink connector config that throws the error you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant adding more databases to the DB server, not in the connector.

I have identified the issue, it is related to the topic name having `prefix.dbo.tablename` which is considered by the connector as another database.

`table.name.format` works fine but when I only have one topic. There is an issue raised here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/731 to support table prefix which would be ideal but looks like it is still open.